# Launching a projectile and landing it in a specific spot with different elevations?

Tags: c#, physics, mathematics

I have a starting position for a projectile and a target position I want it to land on given an initial x and y velocity.

Doing this on a level field is fairly straightforward but I'm struggling to figure out how to do it on two different levels.

I've crudely illustrated what I'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

Comment: You can calculate where it will land based on a given velocity, or calculate what velocity you want based on a given landing position, which one do you want? Since this is basically a high school physics problem with not much relation to game development, I'm not sure if this is the best site for this question.

Comment: I've provided a general method for both 2D and 3D ballistics in C# in this answer: [How can I launch a GameObject at a target if I am given everything except for its launch angle?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/114522/how-can-i-launch-a-gameobject-at-a-target-if-i-am-given-everything-except-for-it)