# Unity 2D Parabolic character movement between platforms displays unexpected behaviour

Tags: unity, 2d, physics, movement

I am trying to write an enemy AI that jumps between available platforms when it doesn't have ground below its feet. I want the character to do the jumps in a parabolic fashion rather than doing a straight jump between them as shown in the image below:

[image]

And to do the arc motion, I use this function and set the actor's velocity to the value returned:

```
    public static Vector2 GetVelocityForArc(Vector3 arcStartPos, Vector3 arcTargetPos, float objectGravityScale, float arrivalTimeVal) {
        float velocityX = (arcTargetPos.x - arcStartPos.x) / arrivalTimeVal;
        float velocityY = (float)((arcTargetPos.y - arcStartPos.y - 0.5 * (Physics.gravity.y * 
objectGravityScale) * Mathf.Pow(arrivalTimeVal, 2)) / arrivalTimeVal);

        return new Vector2(velocityX, Mathf.Abs(velocityY));
}
```

However my function doesn't seem to perform properly. If the target is higher than start position the target just does a straight jump to the target rather than a parabolic one, and sometimes it gets too much X velocity. How can I achieve the parabolic jumps that I'm trying to achieve? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just by your image, the highest point of your arc is once closer to the start jump and once closer to the end jump.

Comment: @Zibelas yeah I haven't done a great job with the visualization haha, the arc should be higher.

Comment: How are you computing your `arrivalTimeVal`? We have lots of [past Q&A showing how to compute a velocity to follow a parabolic arc](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/114547/39518) that you may be able to apply. What makes the x velocity "too much" and how should we judge what amount is correct? What behaviour would you *like* to see when the target is higher (there are many parabolas we could choose - what characterizes the one you want)?