# Mouse position as target, with arced (curved) shot

Tags: python, projectile-physics

I am trying to write a game with artillery mortar fire I have another gun adjusting & firing
towards the mouse, but would like to switch weapons.

I am having problems with how to fire a shell up in a curved arc and have it come back down on a target (the mouse position).

I have searched for some thing like what I'd like, but can't find anything.

This code is for my player gun rotating and firing toward the mouse:

```
import pygame, math, random
import os


pygame.init()

#Initialize variables:
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
screen_width = 960
screen_height = 720
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width,screen_height))
green = 0,255,0
red = 255,0,0
blue = 0,0,255
yellow = 255,255,0
white = 255,255,255
black = 0,0,0

gun_pos_x = 116
gun_pos_y = 589

    class Player_gunner(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
        def __init__(self, x, y):
        pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        super().__init__()
            self.image = pygame.image.load(os.path.join('sprites', 'player_gun.png'))
            self.rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))
        self.rotation = True
        self.weapon = "gun"

    def update(self):
        player_pos  = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))
        player_rect = self.image.get_rect(center = (self.x, self.y))

        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
        dx, dy = mx - player_rect.centerx, my - player_rect.centery
        angle = math.degrees(math.atan2(-dy, dx))

        rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, angle)
        angle2 = math.degrees(math.atan2(-dy, dx))
        rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, angle2)

        if angle < 0 and angle > -179.99:
            angle = 0
            rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, angle)
        if angle > 90 and angle < 180.99:
            angle = 90
            rot_image = pygame.transform.rotate(self.image, angle)
        rot_image_rect = rot_image.get_rect(center = player_rect.center)
        screen.blit(rot_image, rot_image_rect.topleft)

    class Shell_circle:
        def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, speed):
        self.rect = pygame.Rect(x,y,width,height)
        self.color = color
        self.speed = speed
        self.radius = 2.8
        def draw(self, screen):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen,black,(self.x, self.y),self.radius) # Draw shell circle

    class Shell(Shell_circle):
    def __init__(self, color, x, y, width, height, speed, targetx,targety):
        super().__init__(color, x, y, width, height, speed)
        self.angle = math.atan2(targety-y, targetx-x) #get angle to target in radians
        self.speed = speed
        self.dx = math.cos(self.angle)*self.speed
        self.dy = math.sin(self.angle)*self.speed
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
    def move(self):


        self.x = self.x + self.dx
        self.y = self.y + self.dy

        if self.x <= 120:
            self.x = self.x = 120

        if not screen.get_rect().collidepoint(self.x,self.y):
            shells.remove(s)
#   Object set up
player_gunner = Player_gunner(gun_pos_x, gun_pos_y)
player_gunner.rect.x = gun_pos_x   # go to x
player_gunner.rect.y = gun_pos_y   # go to y
player_gun = pygame.sprite.Group()
player_gun.add(Player_gunner(player_gunner.rect.x, player_gunner.rect.y))

#Sprite Group lists
shells = []

#Main program loop
done = False
while not done:

    screen.fill(white) #fill screen with black

    #Get user input
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
            x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
            s = Shell(black, gun_pos_x, gun_pos_y, 4,4, 12, x,y)
            shells.append(s)

    player_gun.update()

    #Update game objects
    for s in shells:
        s.move()
        s.draw(screen)

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(30) #30 FPS
pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: "Can't find anything" really? I could swear [I'd written at least a few answers](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/114522/39518) on the [tag:projectile-physics] tag showing how to aim/determine the initial velocity of a lobbed projectile so it's parabolic arc hits a given target...  Key words like "ballistic" and "parabola" help. When you search this past Q&A, are you able to find your solution, or do you need help adapting any particular parts to your use case?

Comment: @DMGregory I appreciate all the work you have done, but I just looked at your link and its for Unity I have no clue what I am looking at, I would like some thing I can understand, I have also searched with those keywords and still nothing, Thank you.

Comment: Can you edit your question to walk through the example code and point out what parts you need help understanding? The more precisely you can identify the parts you need help with, the better folks can target answers to help you with those parts.