# Predictive Aiming To Update Every Frame

Tags: unity, c#

I am making a 2D bow and arrow game, and I want there to be a predictive aiming line as you pull the bow back. The problem is, in my current script, it seems to only update every time I go to shoot, rather than updating as you pull the bow back. For clarity, it updates the direction, but not the increased force as you pull the bow back further.

I have put this for loop at the top of `Update()`:

```
for(int i = 0; i < Points.Length; i++){
                Points[i].transform.position = PointPosition(i * time);          
            }
```

That calls this method:

```
Vector2 PointPosition(float t){
        force = new Vector2(Mathf.Clamp((startPoint.x - endPoint.x) / damp, powerMin, powerMax), Mathf.Clamp((startPoint.y - endPoint.y) / damp, powerMin, powerMax));
        Vector2 currentPointPos = (Vector2)transform.position + ((-direction.normalized * (force*mult) * t) + 0.5f * Physics2D.gravity * (t*t));
        return currentPointPos;
    }
```

The predicted path is also wrong, but that is a problem for future me. For now, I'm just trying to figure out how I can get the predicted force of this line to update every second. The obvious solutions like setting `force` at the top of `Update()` didn't seem to work, and I don't know if I'm missing a Unity thing or if I've just been staring at my code for too long and can't see the obvious fix.

Comment: Related:  https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/114547/41345

Comment: Related:  https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/71440/41345

Answer (score 0):

Meta re: your question - I'd suggest adding more code to complete your example. More context around which `GameObjects` you are calling `Update()` from could be useful for folks helping to answer your question.

Shot in the dark - If your goal is to get a bit of code to run once every second, you could probably achieve that fairly easily by keeping a running timer in your `GameObject` and checking it via `Update()`:

````
// ...

private float timer = 0.0f;
public float timerThreshold = 0.1f;
 
// ...

void Update () {
  timer += Time.deltaTime;
 
  if (timer >= timerThreshold) {
    timer -= timerThreshold; // Reset timer
    /*
      Execute code as needed to update projectile path preview
      ...
    */
  }
}

// ...
```
````

Comment: One tip for better timing consistency: replace `timer = 0` with `timer -= timerThreshold`. This way you keep any "loose change" fractions of seconds left over from overshooting your target time, and you'll trigger future timed actions correspondingly sooner. Without this, the observed time interval will tend to be longer than the value you set by about half a frame, so over a long time span you'll get fewer timed actions than you'd expect by dividing the span by the timing interval. Using `-=` helps it stay closer to the expected value on average, catching up a little when needed.

Comment: @DMGregory Great tip, edited code snippet to reflect!